# The connection from bathtub overflow pipe to overflow hole in bathtub hole is missing. I have no access behind or underneath Bathtub

Tags: bathtub, overflow, accessibility

The elbow from my bathtub overflow pipe to the overflow hole in my bathtub is missing. I have no access behind or from below my tub. I have been searching the net for solutions before tearing up my freshly reglazed tiles. So far - no luck. Any creative solutions are welcome.

[image]

Comment: Come to peace with tearing up tiles, if there's no access through non-tiled wall (*i.e.* sometimes the bathtub can be reached from a bedroom or closet adjoining - or from the ceiling of the room below it (but no, you said not)- At least come to peace with a mess being made *somewhere,* since access doors/panels seem to be terribly out of fashion.)

Comment: Or come to peace with not over filling your bathtub.  Funny it went missing, since most of them are solidly mounted.  If you promise not to over fill, and give me your first born if you do, then you can probably use some silicon to place a nice cover over the hole for now.  It should be fixed in the near future.

Comment: It is probably back there and needs to be fished forward with a wire bent into a hook shape. No self-respecting plumber/tile guy/contractor would complete that finish work without it... have you looked carefully with a flashlight?